# How to stop Centos 7 Desktop returning to Login Screen after a successful login?

Tags: linux, authentication, centos, centos7, gnome-3

So I just did a fresh install of Centos 7 with the desktop. After the install, I installed my development environment and when to attach my windows ssd, but was told it needed to be shutdown instead of hibernation. So I restarted my system, booted into windows, and hit shutdown. Afterwards, I went to login into my Centos 7 System, and after a successful password entry, it'll start the login process, and then flash a black screen. Soon it'll show Started virtualization daemon, and then load the login screen again!

Why is it doing this? How can I fix it? Then how can I avoid this in the future!?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interrupt the boot at the GRUB stage and boot to runlevel 1, AKA single user mode. Interrupt GRUB by typing a character such as "space" then append to the kernel line by typing "a", backspacing through "rhgb quiet" and appending " 1". This will give you a root shell and not a login prompt. 
From there you can comment all recent entries in /etc/environment , and reboot your server/PC

Comment: There is nothing in my /etc/environment, and after reboot issue is still going.

Comment: This comment is years later, but my system borked again, this helped me not have to do my reinstall solution again.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problem on Centos 6.7 after the yum update and fix with the below steps.

I noticed some commands not working on the terminal, which can be opened via CTRL+ALT+F4 on the login screen.

> -bash: startx: command not found

I have opened a file under /etc/profile.d with root privileges.

> nano /etc/profile.d/fix.sh

and added command to set missing definitions to PATH

> export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

After restarting the OS, everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

My OS RedHat Enterprise Linux 7.4

After a yum update to Redhat 7.5, which includes kernel upgrade and a whole bunch of other updates, RedHat 7.5 wouldn't login and bounce/redirect back to login GUI/screen.

Here's what worked for me:

1. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
2. Elevate to sudo or root
3. chown -R ram:ram /home/ram     # <- Change $HOME directory ownership recursively for problematic user. Use user:group combination relevant for you
4. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and try login again. 
   I was able to login.

**Solution:2**
If above doesn't work for you, you could also [undo last yum update](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system_administrators_guide/sect-yum-transaction_history#sect-Yum-Transaction_History-Reverting).

```
yum history list
yum history info id_number
yum history undo id_number
```

and then reboot.

If you can't even get a prompt with key combination <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, [boot into single user mode](https://www.tecmint.com/boot-into-single-user-mode-in-centos-7/) and try *Solution:2*

This should work for CentOS & Fedora as well.

Comment: This worked for me.  My username was 'oracle'. So the solution was:  chown -R oracle: oracle /home/oracle #

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reinstalling the os. However, I ended up getting the same issue. It was a two part error. So adding anything to my /etc/environment file caused the system not to login. Also, after you install, you need to sudo /etc/passwd because the gnome-init-shell and gdm need to have :/sbin/nologin removed. It's kind of stupid that we have to do that extra step. Now if you were like me, installed everything and dread the reinstall, you can place in the boot disk/usb and go to recovery mode. It'll show you how to get to your system and from there, its just using vi to fix the passwd.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue via a search. Turns out CentOS may not like usernames with periods in them. When I logged into shell, it said /home/first.last does not exist. For reference, I was installing this: http://central-7-0-x86-64.rocksclusters.org/roll-documentation/base/7.0/install-frontend-7.html

Answer (score 0):

you can refer my solution, because i use mv command to rename my name dir，causing a login infinite loop. when i again use mv command to recover my name dir

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).